# When is collection of sets {$B_i, \ i \in I$} forms a partition of set $\cup_{i\in I} B_i$?

Tags: set-theory

When is collection of sets {$B_i, \ i \in I$} forms a partition of set $\cup_{i\in I} B_i$ ?

Now If given collection is mutually disjoint then they form partition. But i don't know how to mathematically prove this?

Thanks

Comment: With what exactly are you having problems in doing this?

Comment: what definition of partition do you use?

Answer (score 0):

a partition of a set $X$ is a family of subsets of $U_i, i \in I$ of $X$ such that $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I } U_i=X$ and such that they are all pairwise disjoint.

In your case the first condition is obviously met. So you just need the second one.